# Hanger or recommendations for steel hanger for deck beam

Tags: beam, hanger

I am building a deck.  One of the beams (beam 1 in sketch) is a 20' x 5-1/4" PSL beam.  The beam is sitting on a 6x6 concrete post with a carport post saddle on one side.  My plan is then to mount two steel L brackets with threaded bar nutted and epoxied into a 8" concrete wall of the house.  I'd place one at mid span and one at the other end.

The beam will sit 1" from the concrete wall.  I'd like to bolt the L to the concrete and then lag screw from the bottom of the L up into the beam.  Is there existing hardware that would work for this or do I just need to get something made?  If I do get something made what thickness should I go for?  I was thinking 1/4" HDG 6"H x 6.25" shelf for the legs and maybe 6" for the width.

I don't want to do posts and more footings and I think this approach is better than bolting the PSL through a 1" piece of ply and directly to the concrete.  If the beam ever rots and it is just attached to the two Ls it would be quite easy to replace.  If it is bolted to the concrete everywhere I think it will be quite a bit more challenging.  I also think that drill all the holes and bolting the beam would be more work than just mounting the two steel Ls.

Thanks for reading !

[image]

Comment: So the deck _isn't_ self-supported. It's bearing on the house foundation. You're asking us to engineer a load-bearing steel structure that will carry substantial torque loads on a wall we don't know much about. This isn't the place for that. Consult a local engineer. Be sure to ask about your epoxy plan. I'd expect that sleeve anchors would be specified.

Comment: You're right--shear bolts through the beam aren't a good idea. No engineer or inspector would pass that.

Comment: TBF, @isherwood, the drawing does specify (at the bottom left) `8" concr`, which I presume is an 8" concrete wall. Though I agree that this does belong on the "closed because it needs a structural engineer" heap. (though there's been an argument about that lately, too.)

Comment: That doesn't mean we can hang whatever we like on it, of course. I'm in the camp who doesn't jerk knees to the engineer requirement, but this is a pretty clear-cut scenario to me.

Comment: I have an engineer.  I did ask him, he replied for this question "I am not clear but it sounds OK".  I'll follow up with him to make him clear.  I have done rim joists threaded bar epoxied into concrete and nutted to support 1/2 the load of a floor assembly - the middle half supported by post and beam - before so I don't see why it wouldn't work here but it is more work.